# How do I enable Java to do JNLP in Safari?

Tags: safari, java

We use the Java Network Launch Protocol to load up our applications at work, but it's failing for our Mac users now.  I VNC'd into my test Mac to give it a test, and it appears that nothing happens at all.  In the past, if Java wasn't installed it would give the install option, and if it was install it would to a launch.  Now the URL bar just flashes and goes back to the previous website.  Appears that perhaps some recent OS X update has broken this functionality.  How can I re-enable it?

Comment: Have you tried an alternate browser yet? (i.e. Firefox). I ended up having a similar issue with a KVM that required Java. The software would not work via Safari even with Java installed. Ended up using Firefox and it works fine. The software in question also uses JNLP.

Comment: @Mort - Make that an answer and I'll accept it.  I installed Chrome and it works fine there.  Just doesn't work in Safari anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy solution is to utilize an alternate browser. I had a similar issue with a Keyboard Video Mouse switch that required Java in order to initiate a [JNLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) (Java Web Start) session. After installing various versions of Java (1.6, 1.7, etc.) (O.S. is Mountain Lion) and trying to start a JNLP session in Safari (Version 6.0.5, [8536.30.1]) would see the efforts subsequently fail. I installed Google Chrome (Version 28.0.1500.71) and tried to initiate a JNLP session and it worked fine. Firefox may or may not work equally as well but I did not test beyond Google Chrome.